# FailNotEquals expects AnsiString as 2nd parameter

Tags: freepascal

I am writing a test case using fpc unit in lazarus, doing some investigation on how TDateTime behaves.

Now the question is why the counterpart of AssignEquals, which I presume is FailNotEquals can't accept the parameters to be Word, Word as AssignEquals can.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TTestCase1.Test3;
    var d1, d2: TDateTime;
    var hour1, minute1, second1, ms1: Word;
    var hour2, minute2, second2, ms2: Word;
begin
  d2:=Now;
  Sleep(10);
  d1:=Now;

  DecodeTime(d1, hour1, minute1, second1, ms1);
  DecodeTime(d2, hour2, minute2, second2, ms2);

  //AssertEquals(ms1, ms2); // This test fails as expected
  FailNotEquals(ms1, ms2); // Cant compile, param 2 must be AnsiString

  AssertEquals(d1, d2); // How can this slip through...
end;
```

test

Comment: Do you understand the error message? What is the function's signature? What do the docs say?

Comment: FWIW, I'm wondering what FailNotEquals really is. Is sound like it's identical to AssertEquals. You want AssertNotEqual, if it exists, which I suspect it doesn't. The assertions in fpcunit seem limited.

Comment: Nope, no AssertNotEqual, is there a test framework that should be used instead of fpcunit?

Comment: fptest is I think the main alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FailNotEquals` is defined in `DUnitCompatibleInterface.inc` as:

```
class procedure FailNotEquals(expected, actual: string;
        msg: string = ''; errorAddr: Pointer = nil); virtual;
```

The method is not overloaded, so only the string parameters are accepted.